# Any way to style specific letters from a title attribute?

Tags: html, css

Is it at all possible for me to style just the `th` in '12th'? When you hover this div it will display the title, but I just need to figure out if it's possible to style the `th`...
Any help is appreciated

```css
div[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;      
}
```

```html
<div title="12th">
    This is some text. Hover Me.
</div>
```

Comment: Is it always the last two characters that you want to style differently? Does the title always have 4 characters or could it be any length?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should elaborate your question more.
But according to your question I found a way.

Since I don't have enough 'reputation' to comment but you can use just a trick.

```css
div[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;      
}
div[title]:hover:before {
  content: '  th';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  color:red;
  left: 18px; 
  z-index:99;     
}
```

```html
<div title="12th">
    This is some text. Hover Me.
</div>
```

In this you can use `:after`  for highlighting 'th' and make its z-index more than `:before` so that it can come over that.and also make it's position so that it overcomes on 'th' only.

Here's the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So this is a solution.

```css
.fancy:hover {
  position: relative;
}
.fancy:hover > .show-hover {
  display: inline-block;
}

.show-hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25em;
  left: 0;
}

.highlight {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<p class="fancy">
  Lorem ipsum - hover here
  <span class="show-hover">12<span class="highlight">th</span></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it well.. I need to be using the the code I provided (title tag and the div)

Comment: Can you explain, how is the current html generated, that it can't be changed?
Is it always going to be the last 2 characters the highlighted ones? or only 'th'.
'st' 'nd' 'rd' ??

Answer (score 0):

You can get a before pseudo element to be styled the way you want the last two characters and an after element which will show just the first two.

Here's the snippet:

```css
div[title]:hover:after, div[title]:hover:before {
  content: attr(title);
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;  
}
/* this is where you do the styling of the last 2 characters */
div[title]:hover:before {
  color: magenta;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div[title]:hover:after {
  width: 2ch; /* set this to num. chars in the title minus 2 */
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div title="12th">
    This is some text. Hover Me.
</div>
```

Note: this assumes we know the number of characters in the title (in this case 4 which leaves two at the start of the string). A monospace font is used, though it works reasonably well for a normal font - will depend on the actual characters used.